# Set Claim after login using IdentityServer in different software

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have two software and would like to integrate to a single `identityserver`. both are software is multi tenant, using shared database

All tables have a column named TenantId and in my `DbContext` (EF Core) I filter `Where(x => x.TenantId == TenantId)`. Currently I store this TenantId in claim and use a simple solution to generate JWT

In google searches, I have seen that one way to add claim in the access_token is through the `ProfileService`, but my problem is that in each software the user may have different TenantId

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49302420/how-to-add-additional-claims-in-api-project-when-using-identityserver-4) question they are using `OnTokenValidated` to add new Claims

But I wonder, who returns the acess_token for the software? The API or IdentityServer because in this case you need to be the API to add the new Claims

Summary: I want the `identityserver` only to login and generate token, authorization and other logics will be directly in each of the softwares

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the link that you've added you can see that the access_token actually isn't modified. What happens is that the claims from the access_token are mapped to the User.Identity. And in `OnTokenValidated` additional claims are added to this User.Identity.

The problem is that tenantid doesn't fit as claim because IdentityClaims are supposed to model the Identity, which are independent of the context, while something as tenantid's is context dependend.

For the resource you can't use `OnTokenValidated`. Instead use middleware. I suggest you take a look at the solution from the IdentityServer team: the [PolicyServer](https://leastprivilege.com/2018/01/17/announcing-policyserver/).

In short, after authentication (IdentityServer) the policyserver adds claims to the User.Identity based on the configured authorization.

There are two parts in the API (=resource):

1. Extend the User.Identity with authorization claims
2. Policies, as this where the logic should take place.

And then you'll have what you want. Resource based authorization.

The PolicyServer uses a json settings file, but you can extend this with your own store. The example is missing normal claims, but you can extend the Policy model with claims:

```
// Just the lines to include claims.
public class Policy
{
    public List<Claim> Claims { get; internal set; } = new List<Claim>();

    internal Task<PolicyResult> EvaluateAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user)
    {
        var claims = Claims.Select(x => new Claim { Name = x.Name, Value = x.Value }).ToArray();

        var result = new PolicyResult()
        {
            Claims = claims
        };
    }
}
```

And in the configuration:

```
"Policy": {
  "claims": [
    {
      "name": "tenantid",
      "value": "44"
    }
  ],
  "roles": [
```

In the middleware add the claims to the User.Identity, e.g.:

```
id.AddClaims(claims);
```

Comment: Each request processed by middliware have to access the database to return the claims?

Comment: @MarceloDias It depends on the strategy, but yes this could be the case. The local PolicyServer version uses a config file, where changes are noticed. You can instead implement in-memory caching, as long as changes are noticed. But you can also change your design and make it part of the query in the business context. E.g. the very existence of a (active) user in the business user table means the user is authorized to do something.